# How to store a boolean value in an Informix database?

Tags: informix

I have created an insert statement for the Informix database (version IBM Informix Dynamic Server version 14.10.FC10AEE).

This looks like the following:

```
INSERT INTO person ('name', is_active)
VALUES ('peter', true);
```

| column | Data type |
| --- | --- |
| id | serial |
| name | char(50) |
| is_active | boolean |

I get the following error message:

> SQL Error [42000]: A syntax error has occurred.

I suspect it is because the boolean value **true** cannot be processed correctly by Informix.

I had already tried it with the value **1**, which did not work either.
I get the following error message:

> SQL Error [IX000]: Value does not match the type of column (is_active).

Does anyone have an idea how I can solve the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The legal values for the boolean data type are `'t'` `'f'` and `null`. The quotes for the true and false values are required.